# How to know html ready event is triggered or not in sencha

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2

I am working on **sencha touch** app here my view is not rendering on Android device 5.1.1 with Android system WebView version 46.0 but working fine in below version of WebView  .

Answer (score 0):

Add the below script in your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var mobile = false;
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){mobile = true; onDeviceReady();}, false);
    } else {
        $(document).ready(onDeviceReady);   
    }
    function onDeviceReady() {
        setEvents();
        test();
        if (mobile) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Debugging-ready for\n" + navigator.userAgent);
        } else {
            alert("Debugging-ready for\n" + navigator.userAgent);
        }
    };
</script>
```

And now you can do whatever you want inside onDeviceReady() method. Let me know if it helps.